# custom twitter-bootstrap pagination

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change bootstrap pagination so that there is no border, but a border appears on hover and around active a. I achieved some strange effect-when there is whiteness [whiteness on the border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh9kn.jpg) on one of the borders. What have I done wrong?

```css
.pagination{ 
 height: 25px;
 a.left-arrow{
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin:0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-image: url("../img/arrow-left.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center left;
}
 a.right-arrow{
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-image: url("../img/arrow-right.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center right;
 }
}
.pagination > li > a, .pagination > li > span{
 padding: 0 8px;
 margin-left: 0;
 border: none;
 color: $text-color;
 font-size: 18px;
}
.pagination > li > a:hover, .pagination > li > a.active{
 background-color: white;
 color: $second-color;
 border: 1px solid $second-color;
 border-radius: 0;
 margin: -1px;
}
.pagination > li > a.right-arrow:hover, .pagination > li > a.left-arrow:hover{
 border: none;
 margin: 0;
 margin-top: 5px;
 opacity: 0.5;
 color: blue;
}
.pagination > li > span:hover{
 background-color: white;
 border: none;
 }
```

```html
<nav class="pager">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="left-arrow" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"class="active">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><span>...</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="right-arrow" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Well the strange effect that you encountered is that everything shifts to the left on hover? If yes that's because you add a `margin: -1px` on hover. Get rid of that and also get rid of `border: 1px solid $second-color;` if you don't want borders

Comment: On the contrary I need a border, but only on hover or when the item is active.